# Mouse and Keyboard for XBox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, keyboard

I know there are third party attachments you can get like the XFPS Sniper or the Mayflash Max. So two questions really.

1: Has Microsoft given a reason why they decided not to allow the use of a mouse on the XBox?

2: Do the XFPS Sniper or Mayflash Max really work? I have heard there are some latency issues.

Comment: This seems more like a game dev question, as that's the reason why. It's all up to the game devs on how they want input to work.

Comment: No offense @Jack but this seems largely argumentative.  Do you think you could rephrase it?

Comment: @tzenes That's a fair statement. I know it's a heated subject but I tried to keep it to a straight forward question. If it will help I will see what I can do to make it a bit more straight forward.

Comment: @McKay Is that true? I have heard it was a designed limitation of the XBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to take some time to look this up (and plug things into my xbox) and I learned the following:

- The Xbox 360 will accept keyboard and mouse input (I'm actually guessing on the mouse as it didn't do anything, but the 360 didn't complain).
- This input is different in nature than the controller (thus you can't use it to play Halo for example)
- You can use this to type into the Xbox Dashboard in any Text Input field.

I dug deeper into the XNA api and found the following:

- The XNA Keyboard class provides different Enum from the Xbox controller
- There is no explicit cast between the two (though a developer could write one)
- The Keyboard and Controller are polled differently (so a developer must poll it separately from the Controller)
- Because of the previous point, there is no built in way to associate a keyboard hooked into the 360 with an account without explicitly doing so (ie. the api doesn't handle this for you).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the XNA Keyboard class is mostly intended for PC-Based XNA games.

Answer (score 0):

The Mayflash Max Shooter does work. I own one and just wrote a fairly detailed [blog entry](http://geekdadslife.blogspot.com/2011/01/mayflash-max-shooter-playing-xbox-360.html) about it because I couldn't find a lot of information about it when I was shopping around for one. However I don't think any one of these tools, besides *maybe* the XIM2 will work like you think they will.

EDIT: I sold the Max Shooter and now I bought a XIM, which [I've also reviewed](http://geekdadslife.blogspot.com/2011/02/maximus-xim-playing-xbox-360-with-mouse.html) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any USB keyboard with your Xbox 360, however most games aren't coded with support for keyboard/mouse input (none to my recollection actually).

Answer (score 0):

I was just interested in getting a keyboard to work with the Xbox 360 for entering passwords and navigating the dashboard just like my PS4 does. I tried using my Lenovo KU-1255 with an integrated trackpoint and Logitech DiNovo Edge, but they were not recognised.

Then I tried the special USB port on my Aten CS1794 HDMI KVMP switch with keyboard emulation and was surprised that the same keyboards worked on this particular port.

**Conclusion:** Plain USB keyboards work, keyboards with integrated pointing devices/functionality don't.