# Can I use a keyboard on Xbox One in the dashboard?

Tags: xbox-one, keyboard

On Xbox 360 and PS4 I can use my keyboard for entering passwords and navigating the dashboard. (Xbox 360 only works with plain USB keyboards, [as I found out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/215807/50186).) I have been unable to make my keyboards work with the Xbox One yet. What do I need to do?

Comment: I do vaguely remember so... I think... I used it for my account details once

Comment: USB keyboard support was added in an update on February 11, 2014. This should allow you to use any generic USB keyboard in the dashboard. I guess you should try some different keyboards or check that the USB port on your Xbox is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work according to the [operating system versions and system updates page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/system-update-operating-system) which I just stumbled over:

> OS version: 6.2.10542 (xb_rel_1402.140213-0115) fre
>
> Release date 2/14/2014
>
> New or updated features
>
> - Update to My game & apps to allow sorting of games and application lists, and separate queue lists for games, applications, and installs.
> - Ability to delete game and application saved data.
> - Improved installation and DLC management.
> - Addition of the controller battery power indicator.
> - Improved UI for accessing friends, achievements, messages, and party chat.
> - Game DVR app to be included in the Xbox OneGuide as an app channel.
> - Update to the boot progress indicators for system update.
> - Improve consistency of UX for update and install progress.
> - Separate game, application, and install queue lists.
> - **Addition of USB keyboard support.**
>
> Stability and performance update
>
> - Improved NAT detection.
> - Network Troubleshooter improvements.
> - Blu-ray quality improvements.
> - Significant performance and stability improvements.
>
> Additional details
>
> [Xbox Wire](http://news.xbox.com/2014/02/xbox-one-keeps-getting-better)